# BUILTIN\Administrators removed - how to undo it

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

SQL Server 2000 Standard, Windows 2003
My coworker removed 'BUILTIN\Administrators' group from SQL Server which results in 'SQL Server Agent' not working.
All my TSQLs to synchronize databases stopped working.


I have Administrator rights on the server and my database user is in sysadmin role.


Does any one have idea how to bring 'BUILTIN\Administrators' back without restoring master  database from backup?

**Edit:** When I try to add Administrators or MACHINENAME\Administrators using Enterprise Manager I have this group on the list to choose, but when I accept my choice I have error:

`Error 15041: Windows NT user or group 'MACHINENAME\Administrators' not found. Check the name again`

of course instead of MACHINENAME I see my server name


**Edit2:** Found it

1. Login as sysadmin
2. Run following TSQL queries
   `EXEC sp_grantlogin 'BUILTIN\Administrators'`
   and 
   `EXEC sp_addsrvrolemember 'BUILTIN\Administrators','sysadmin'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to re-add 'BUILTIN\Administrators' as it is a SQL Server 2000 security flaw. All domain administrators will have full sysadmin rights to your SQL Server to drop databases etc.

Find the account that is running SQL Agent (Right click SQL Server agent in enterprise manager and select properties). Then add this account as a SQL Server login using windows authentication and add it to the sysadmin fixed server role.

Answer (score 1):

Another method is to connect to your SQL Server database with the "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" account. [This approach](http://www.top-password.com/blog/how-to-reset-forgotten-sa-password-without-stopping-sql-server-instance/) requires you to start SQL Server Management Studio as the system account. After connect, you can create a new login or reset sa password.

Answer (score 0):

Using Enterprise Manager, can't you just go into Logins and add "Administrators" as a Windows Login to the server?  Then add the login to the sysadmin role?

If you can't use "Administrators", try "MACHINENAME\Administrators" (obviously substituting MACHINENAME for the actual name).

Sorry I don't have a more definitive answer, I don't really want to try it :)